# how to use 'ReDim Preserve' in excel vba when I don't know the upper bound value

Tags: excel, vba

I need to populate an array from variable values that are generated during processing a `.txt` file. However the upper bound depends on input lines. How can I make the following thing work?

```
Dim myArr As Variant
ReDim Preserve myArr(1)  ' this line does not work without a value

Do While (some condition)
    myArr=Trim(variable_name)
Loop
```

Comment: Are you looping through all lines in your .txt file an placing values in your array that way?

Comment: When a certain condition is met, yes, i need to load the following x lines into an array. Every line would be every value.

Comment: Check for the conditions in a loop and increment a counter and then redim the array in 1 line. There will be 2 loops but still this will be faster

Comment: Gather the lines that pass the check into a `Collection` or `Dictionary` object.  Than create and populate your array.  The `.Count` property will give you the size.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's little code snippt that should help you understand:

```
Option Explicit
Sub ReDimTest()
    Dim counter As Long
    counter = 0
    Dim arr() As String

    'read first element from file
    Dim firstItem As String: firstItem = "1"
    'increment counter
    counter = counter + 1
    ReDim Preserve arr(counter)
    arr(counter) = firstItem
    'read second element from file
    Dim secondItem As String: secondItem = "2"
    'increment counter
    counter = counter + 1
    ReDim Preserve arr(counter)
    arr(counter) = secondItem
End Sub
```

Comment: just a curiosity....when I used 'Dim arr As Variant' instead of 'Dim arr() As String', it didn't work...any idea why?

Comment: @user3471438 Because if you declare variable as `Variant`, it is not known what is the real type of the variable, thus `ReDim` might not work, since it can be used only with arrays.

Answer (score 3):

Check for the conditions in a loop and increment a counter and then redim the array in 1 line. There will be 2 loops but still this will be faster. Here is one way (**Untested**)

```
Dim myArr As Variant
Dim counter As Long

Do While (some condition)
    counter = counter + 1
Loop

ReDim myArr(counter) '<~~ No need of Preserve

counter = 0

Do While (some condition)
    myArr(counter) = Trim(variable_name)
    counter = counter + 1
Loop
```

Answer (score 0):

By using a counter:

```
Dim myArr As Variant
Dim counter as Integer

Do While (some condition)
    ReDim Preserve myArr(counter)
    myArr(counter)=Trim(variable_name)
Loop
```

To take it a bit further than psuedo-code

```
Dim myArr as Variant
Dim counter as Integer
Dim x as Integer
x = 2

Do While x < 10
    ReDim Preserve myArr(counter)
    myArr(counter) = x
    debug.print Ubound(myArr)
    debug.print myArr(counter)
    x = x * 2 
Loop
```